Can I register the same socket to different kqueue instances, one for EVFILT_READ and another for EVFILT_WRITE?
Can I register the same socket FD to two different kqueue instances(FDs), one for EVFILT_READ and another for EVFILT_WRITE as I want to have different threads to process the send and recv readiness ?
